# <<method name>> was not declared in this scope for a private static method

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I saw the thread earlier called " 'name of method' was not declared in this scope", but the answers didn't really help me at all. The method that this is happening for is a private static method. I am attempting to use it within the class, but it won't work. The name of the method is "nthCoeffCatalan". I'm getting the error every time I use it. I don't know if this will help, but I'm using Code::Blocks with wxWidgets and Mingw32 for a compiler.
Here's the .h file:

```
#ifndef CATALAN_H
#define CATALAN_H

#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Catalan
{
    public:
        Catalan(int);
        virtual ~Catalan( );
        void recursiveRandomGenerator( );
        void boltzmannRandomGenerator( );
        int rank( );
        void unrank(int, int);
        void outputBinaryTree( );
        void outputDyckPath( );
        void outputTriangulation( );
    private:
        int n;
        int catalanObject[];
        int max_size;
        static int nthCoeffCatalan(int);
};

#endif // CATALAN_H
```

Here's the .cpp file:

```
#include <Catalan.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int catalanObject[] = {};
int n;
int max_size;

Catalan::Catalan(int sz){
n = sz;

     //find out the position of the leaf in a tree which is just a node and n-1 right vertices
    max_size = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <=n; i++){
        max_size += pow(2,i);
    }

    catalanObject[max_size];

    for (int i = 0; i < max_size; i++){
        catalanObject[i] = 0;
    }
}

Catalan::~Catalan( ){
    delete &n;
    delete &max_size;
    delete catalanObject;
}

void recursiveRandomGenerator( ){
    //initialize the random number generator
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = n;
    int i = 0;

    //give the tree a root
    catalanObject[i] = 1;
    r--;

    //decide size of left and right trees
    float x = ((float) (rand()%10000))/(10000.0);
    int k = -1;
    float s = 0;
    int a_r = 0;
    int b_k = 0;
    int c_rk = 0;

    //calculate a_r
    if (r == 0){
        a_r = 1;
    }
    else{
        //calculate [x^r] in B(x)^2
        if (r > 1){
            for (int j = r/2; j >= 1; j--){
                int temp = 0;
                if (r%2 == 0 && j == r/2){
                    temp = nthCoeffCatalan(j);
                    temp = temp*nthCoeffCatalan(r-j);
                }
                else{
                    temp = nthCoeffCatalan(j);
                    temp = temp*nthCoeffCatalan(r-j);
                    temp = temp*2;
                }
                a_r += temp;
            }
        }
        //calculate [x^r] in 2B(x)
        a_r += 2*nthCoeffCatalan(r);
    }
    while (x > s){
        k = k + 1;
        //calculate b_k
        if (k == 0){
            b_k = 1;
        }
        else{
            b_k = nthCoeffCatalan(k);
        }
        //calculate c_rk
        if (k == r){
            c_rk = 1;
        }
        else{
            c_rk = nthCoeffCatalan(r-k);
        }
        //re-calculate s
        int temp;
        temp = (float) b_k;
        temp = temp * (float) c_rk;
        temp = temp / (float) a_r;
        s += temp;
    }


}

void boltzmannRandomGenerator( ){

}

int rank( ){
    return 0;
}

void unrank(int rnk, int n){

}

void outputBinaryTree( ){

}

void outputDyckPath( ){

}  

void outputTriangulation( ){

}

static int nthCoeffCatalan(int n){
    int num = 1;
    int den = 1;
    int retVal = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        num = num*(n+i+1); // runs from n+1 to 2n (=2n!/n!)
        den = den*(i+1); // runs from 2 to n (=n!)
    }

    retVal = num/den;

    return retVal;
}
```

### Side Note

Also, as a side note I want to use an array as a class variable but in the constructor, on the line where I initialize the size of the array, my debugger says that the code has no effect. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistakenly providing definitions of *global* functions, but you actually wanted to define *member* functions (whose declarations appear in the class definition of `Catalan`).

So for instance, **in your `.cpp` file**:

```
static int nthCoeffCatalan(int n)
{
    // ...
}
```

Should be:

```
int Catalan::nthCoeffCatalan(int n)
//  ^^^^^^^^^
{
    // ...
}
```

This applies also to other non-static member functions. So for instance (**again in your `.cpp` file**) instead of:

```
void recursiveRandomGenerator( )
{
    // ...
}
```

You should write:

```
void Catalan::recursiveRandomGenerator( )
//   ^^^^^^^^^
{
    // ...
}
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

All of your member function definitions should be qualified as belonging to `Catalan`. So, for example, the definition of `recursiveRandomGenerator` should actually look like:

```
void Catalan::recursiveRandomGenerator( ){
  // ...
}
```

Also, you should not put the `static` keyword before the definition of `nthCoeffCatalan`. It should look like this:

```
int Catalan::nthCoeffCatalan(int n){
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class definition declares a bunch of member functions, including `nthCoeffCatalan`. In the source file, only two members are defined: the constructor and the destructor. All of the rest of the functions are free functions. You have to mark them as member functions by adding `Catalan::` to their names.